# Deleting top row of every sheet on a copied workbook

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv

I'm saving a closed workbook in individual sheets as .csv files for opening in minitab. The code to save each individual sheet as .csv works great. The issue is I also need to delete the top row of each sheet before saving it as .csv without affecting the original file.

The code will work on the first iteration and the .csv file for the first sheet is correct. But once I hit the second loop, I get errors on the code line to delete the top row.

The errors are all listed in the code below next to the variations I've tried.

```vb
Dim objExcel
Dim objWB
Dim objws
Dim myPath As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("file location")

    'prevent overwrite warnings
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
i = 1
For Each objws In objWB.Worksheets
  
  myPath = "\\G:\file location"
    
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Copy
    'objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate 'if this segment of code is active, it also gets Sub script out of range on second loop

    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("a1").EntireRow.Delete 'run-time error 9 Sub script out of range on second loop
    'objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").EntireRow.Delete 'run-time error 1004 Delete method of range class failed on second loop
    'objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.objws.Range("a1").EntireRow.Delete 'error object doesn't support this property or method

    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & objws.Name, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    
    i = i + 1
 
Next

    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: `objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows(1).Delete`

Comment: Shouldn't `objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Copy` be `objws.Copy`?

Answer (score 1):

Likely two issues:

1. `objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Copy` should be `objws.Copy`.
2. Then, `objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows(1).Delete` to delete the first row in the copied worksheet.

Note that `i` is likely superfluous.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. After adding these changes, now I'm getting 1004: Delete method of range class failed on  ```objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows(1).Delete```  on the second iteration of the loop.
Could the fact that this is happening on the second iteration be a hint of what the base error is?

Comment: My guess would be that somehow `objWb` is the active workbook, or that the copied sheet is protected

Comment: I was copying a protected sheet. Ended up just deleting the top row in the source file since it wasn't entirely necessary anyways.